# is it possible to get only the associated product count from shopping cart?

Tags: magento

I am working on a Ajax cart for my website. I am trying to validate Configurable products for the stock availability. Please consider below case

```
Cotton shirt (Product ID : 421 - Configurable Product)
  Size : L (Product ID : 425 - Simple product)
  Size : M (Product ID : 436 - Simple product)
```

User should select at least one size to add product to the cart.

When i added this product with "Size L" twice and added this product with "Size M" once.
And when i print the item ids in shopping cart, it shows only the id of Configurable product (421).

How do i get ids of Simple product which are really being added to the cart?

Comment: Please mention a file where you are printing out the IDs.

Comment: in the /var/mywebsite/app/code/community/J2t/Ajaxcheckout/controllers/IndexController.php (cartAction())

because my ajax request is posted to http://mywebsite.com/j2tajaxcheckout/index/cart/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3Jvb2phLmFjdHNvZnBoaWxvc29waGllLmNvbS93b21lbi9hZXJvcGS13b21lbi9zb2xpZC1sZWdnaW5ncy1ibGFjay5odG1s/product/421/

Comment: what is the code of the collection of items in cart looking like?

Comment: i cannot print the items in cart as full array... the page gets crashed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to check if the product in the cart is configurable, then if it is you can get the information stored in the product options to work out the simple product that was actually added. The below code should help a bit:

```
if($product['product_type']=='configurable'){
    $options = unserialize($product['product_options']);
    $simpleProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$options['simple_sku']);
}
```

Comment: is there any way for me to get the product options from this code $items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems(); Because i don't get any values when i print the product_options..

but i am getting this using $_product->getProductOptions(); is this right?

Comment: If you want to see which products are configurable/simple you can use the below:

$items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();

foreach( $items as $item ){
 echo $item->getProductId();
 echo $item->getProductType();
}